# Subclass in dart forces me to call superclass constructor

Tags: oop, dart, constructor

I am using the dart programming language where I have an abstract class *Vehicle* and a subclass *car*

```
abstract class Vehicle {

  int _tires;
  String _type;


  Vehicle(int tires,String type) {
    this._tires=tires;
    this._type=type;

  }
}
```

```
class car extends Vehicle {

car (int tires, String type)  {
   this._type=type;
   this._tires=tires;
  }

}
```

Both Vehicle and car are in the same library yet I keep getting the error

*The superclass 'Vehicle' doesn't have a zero argument constructor.  Try declaring a zero argument constructor in 'Vehicle', or explicitly invoking a different constructor in 'Vehicle'.*

Why can I not declare a separate constructor in the car subclass? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Since you used `car extends Vehicle`, you've declared that `car` is a derived version of `Vehicle` and should inherit the implementation of `Vehicle`.  To inherit the implementation of `Vehicle`, you'll actually need to construct a `Vehicle`, and that requires invoking a constructor of the base `Vehicle` class.

If you want `car` to provide its own, independent *implementation* of `Vehicle`, then you should use `car implements Vehicle` instead.  That indicates that `car` conforms to the `Vehicle` *interface* but will implement everything itself.  Note that doing so means that `car` would need to provide its own `int _tires` and `String _type` members.

Comment: The dart docs specify that constructors are not inherited. That means that I should be able to provide my own car constructor without the need to construct a Vehicle. I am also not sure what you mean by "to inherit the implementation of Vehicle, you'll actually need to construct a Vehicle, and that requires invoking a constructor of the base Vehicle class."

Comment: Right constructors aren't inherited.  I'm talking about inherited methods.  Suppose that `Vehicle` implements some public method `go()` that uses `_tires`, and `car` inherits it.  How can `Vehicle.go()` guarantee that`_tires` is initialized?  Currently `Vehicle` makes that guarantee because `Vehicle`'s constructor guarantees to initialize it.  If a derived class `car` were not required to invoke the base class constructor, there is no such guarantee that base class members are properly initialized.  What if `Vehicle` added some new (potentially private) data member that `go()` depended on?